# re.search() logically or two patterns in re.search()

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have the following string.

```
Page load for http://xxxx?roxy=www.yahoo.com&sendto=https://mywebsite?ent took 4001 ms (Ne: 167 ms, Se: 2509 ms, Xe: 1325 ms)<br><br><br>Topic: Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite<br>
```

OR

```
Page load for http://xxxx?roxy=www.yahoo.com&sendto=https://mywebsite?ent took too long (12343 ms Ne: 167 ms, Se: 2509 ms, Xe: 1325 ms)<br><br><br>Topic: Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite<br>
```

I want to extract `4001` OR `12343` above from `ent took 4001 ms` OR 
`ent took too long (12343 ms` and assign that to a variable

```
tt = int(re.search(r"\?ent\s*took\s*(\d+)",message).group(1))
```

This regex does match the first part and does return me 4001.How do I logcially or the expression `r"\?ent\s*\took\s*too\s*long\s*\((\d+)"`
to extract 12343 from the second part?

Comment: Did you look on line 242 of /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one matches both patterns in one go and extracts the desired number:

```
tt = int(re.search(r"\?ent took (too long \()?(?P<num>\d+)",message).group('num'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The question mark at the beginning of the regex doesn't follow anything that can be made optional.  If you want to match a literal question mark there, write `\?`:

```
x = int(re.findall(r"\?ent\s*took\s*([^m]*)",message)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to escape `?` at the leading of your pattern, because the `?` mark is a regex character and make a string optional and must precede by a string! so if you want to math `?` you need to use `\?` also as a more efficient way you can use `re.search` and `\d+` in your pattern,and refuse from extra indexing :

```
>>> int(re.search(r"\?ent\s*took\s*(\d+)",s).group(1))
4001
```

For second example you can do :

```
>>> re.search(r'\((\d+)',s).group(1)
'12343'
```

And for match in both cases use the following pattern  :

```
(\d+)[\s\w]+\(|\((\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zG4iG5/1)

```
>>> s1="Page load for http://xxxx?roxy=www.yahoo.com&sendto=https://mywebsite?ent took too long (12343 ms Ne: 167 ms, Se: 2509 ms, Xe: 1325 ms)<br><br><br>Topic: Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite<br>"
>>> s2="Page load for http://xxxx?roxy=www.yahoo.com&sendto=https://mywebsite?ent took 4001 ms (Ne: 167 ms, Se: 2509 ms, Xe: 1325 ms)<br><br><br>Topic: Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite<br>"
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)[\s\w]+\(|\((\d+)',s1).group(2)
'12343'
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)[\s\w]+\(|\((\d+)',s2).group(1)
'4001'
```

Comment: He presumably wants to match the literal `?` that marks the beginning of the query string in the URL.

Comment: @liv2hak for that you can just use `r'\((\d+)'` checkout the edit!

Comment: @Kasra - I don't know which one of the messages I am going to get before hand. I need a pattern that matches both.

Comment: @Kasra - if I use ` tt = int(re.search(r"(\d+)[\s\w]+\(|\((\d+)",message.group(1)))` I get `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @liv2hak but it works fine for me as i added in answer! are you sure that you have run it correctly?